# Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': An object could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webassembly

When trying to store a compiled wasm module in chrome this is the error I get:
Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': An object could not be cloned.

But according to MDN it should be possible.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Caching_modules

Is there a solution?

Comment: see also [localForage/issues/610: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': An object could not be cloned](https://github.com/localForage/localForage/issues/610)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message and the StackOverflow tag it looks like you're using Chrome. As of version 57 (in which WebAssembly was first shipped), Chrome doesn't support [structured cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) of `WebAssembly.Module`. This includes storing to IndexDB as well as `postMessage` to workers.

IndexDB is indeed [spec'd by WebAssembly](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md#structured-clone-of-a-webassemblymodule) and [documented in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Caching_modules) as you point out, but it isn't necessarily implemented by all browsers. You'll have to handle failure gracefully. This is required anyways: IndexDB is allowed to fail for other reasons. Structured cloning might fail even if the browser supports it!

In V8 there's a command line flag to change this behavior: `--wasm-disable-structured-cloning=false`. The same behavior can be change in Chrome with `chrome://flags/#enable-webassembly` (enter this URL in your browser's navigation bar, change the option, restart the browser).

Note that Firefox does support structured cloning as of version 52 (the first to ship WebAssembly).

Comment: so there is no way to handle compiled wasm modules? each time a website want to run a wasm module it will have to recompile the code?

Comment: Chrome is expected to enable structured cloning in a future release; it just didn't make it into version 57.